# How to make the azure web site as https enabled?

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I would like to make my azure web site as https enabled one. As exactly like https://mysite.azurewebsites.net. Though I have uploaded my SSL certificate in certificate section in web site configuration tab its not redirecting automatically. Is there any other settings I have to enable?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have a custom domain?  Also, are you trying to make your site accessible *only* via HTTPS?  The documentation to do this is pretty comprehensive and available here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/.

Comment: You have to configure the redirect if you want https only.  Lots of info out there on that.  https://www.google.com/search?q=azure%20redirect%20to%20https

Comment: Would that be sufficient to upload the ssl certificate and add the redirection entry in web.config into azure websites certificate section?

Comment: You can't secure a MVC app via web.config. See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

Answer (score 1):

So to clarify the sequence of steps:

1. After you configure your custom domain properly, then h_ttp://customdomain.com will point to mysite.azurewebsites.net.
2. After you bind an SSL certificate to a custom domain in a web app, then h_ttps://customdomain.com will point to mysite.azurewebsites.net, using the bound SSL cert. If you still can't access h_ttps://customdomain.com, then you need to check whether you've configured your domain records properly at the domain registrar.
3. At this point, h_ttp://customdomain.com will continue to work. If you want to **enforce HTTPS** for your web app, see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/#bkmk_enforce.